# Generalization of Lebesgue Convergence theorem

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

A generalization of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem tells us that if $f_n \to f$ in probability and $|f_n| \le g \in L^p$, then $|f| \in L^p$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ norm.

Suppose $f_n \to f$ in probability. If $f_n \in L^p$ for every $n$ and $f \in L^p$ also, can I use the theorem above to conclude that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$?

I don't know how to prove formally that $|f_n|$ are dominated.. If it was almost sure convergence I would say that for $n$ *large enough* we have $|f_n| \le f + 1 \in L^p$, but since we have convergence in probability I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setting, the existence of a dominating function may fail and also the conclusion of the dominated convergence theorem: consider the unit interval wih the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure, and $f_n(x):=n^{1/p}\mathbf 1_{ (0,1/n)}   $. It converges to $0$ in probability but not in $\mathbb L^p$.

Comment: But what about probability measures? (I should have specified that).  It has to hold because (I am pretty sure that) this was used by my book when showing that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution.

Comment: The Borel measure on the unit interval is a probability measure, isn't it?

Comment: Of course. I'm sorry, that was stupid. Your example is very helpful and for what concern the proof on the book I had missed a thing but now it's clear.Thanks!